# Delove the truth for the three function same table

Tags: boolean-algebra

Given Boolean functions:

$F(x,y,z)=x'.(y'+z')(x+y'), G(x,y,z)=x'.(z+yz')(x\oplus zy')$

Develop the truth table for the three function in the same table

Answer (score 1):

Partial truth-table to get you started.  Process each term independently.  Final term are ANDs, so all 1's will be 1's.  x′.(z+yz′)(x⊕zy′)
$$
\begin{array}{ccc|cccccccc}
\text{x} & \text{y} & \text{z} & \text{x'} & \text{(y′+z′)} & \text{(x+y′)} & \text{F(x,y,z)} & \text{yz′} & \text{(z+yz′)} & \text{zy′}  & \text{(x⊕zy′)} & \text{G(x,y,z)}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
You should be able to figure it out from there.  Just add more columns.